# Right arrow key closes window

Tags: keyboard

Whenever I press the right arrow key in any type of window the window will minimize.Very frustrating when it comes to playing video games. I'm using a Dell latitude D820. Any suggestions on how to fix it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check your touchpad driver software for options related to this that you might have accidentally activated.